# $K$ is not endowed with any algebraic structure. How can pointwise sum and convolution product be defined on $K^{(S)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm doing Exercise 6 in textbook Algebra by Saunders MacLane and Garrett Birkhoff.

[image]

> If $S$ is an additive monoid, the support of a function $f: S \rightarrow K$ is the set of all those $s \in S$ with $f(s) \neq 0$. Show that the set of all functions $f$ with finite support constitute a ring $K^{(S)}$ under pointwise sum and convolution product, with a suitable unit, and construct a monomorphism $K \rightarrow K^{(S)}$ of rings. (Hint: If $S$ is the additive monoid ${N}$, then $K^{(S)}$ is the ring $K[x]$), The ring $K^{(S)}$ is called the "monoid ring" for S over $K$.

The authors do not endow $K$ with any algebraic structure. How can pointwise sum and convolution product be defined on $K^{(S)}$?

Thank you very much for your clarification!

---

**Update:** @ Angina Seng verified my observation in a comment. Here is my attempt.

For $p,q \in K^{(S)}$, we define addition and multiplication by, for all $x \in S$, $$\begin{aligned} (p + q) (x) &= p(x) + q(x) \\ (p q) (x) &= \sum_{\substack{y+z=x\\p(y) q(z) \neq 0}} p(y) q(z)\end{aligned}$$

Because $p,q$ have finite support, the set $\{(y,z) \in S^2 \mid y+z=x \text{ and } p(y) q(z) \neq 0\}$ is finite and thus the sum is well-defined. Then it's straightforward to verify that $K^{(S)}$ is actually a ring. The additive identity $\mathbf{0}$ is the function whose values are $0$ everywhere. The multiplicative identity $\mathbf{1}$ is the function such that $\mathbf{1}(x) = 1$ if $x = 0$ and $\mathbf{1}(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Consider $\sigma: K \to K^{(S)}$ that maps $r \in K$ to $p \in K^{(S)}$ such that $p(x) = r$ if $x = 0$ and $p(x) = 0$ otherwise. Then $\sigma$ is the required monomorphism.

Comment: There seems to be a presumption that $K$ is a ring here. Without that condition, you can't do it!

Comment: @AnginaSeng, I should have inferred so with "construct a monomorphism $K \rightarrow K^{(S)}$ of **rings**".

Comment: @AnginaSeng I have added my attempt as an update. Could you please have a check on it?